# windows forms array to file

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader, streamwriter

Newbie here, currently studying C# course and totally new to coding and stuff.

Sorry if this question is already been asked, I've been googling for quite some time and still unable to find a proper answer or anything near it.

Question being simple. I have an array that contains string needs to be saved onto a file, needs to be retrieved when required.

example

```
string[] item_name = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
float[] item_cost = {30f,20f,10f};
int[] item_qty = {10,20,30};
```

How do i go about saving all these data into a file (e.g .txt) and then retrieve at a button_click command?

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far and where the problem is.

Comment: Array of what? Strings? Objects? Bytes?

Comment: To get started, read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Once you've tried something and it didn't work, get back to ask a more specific question.

Comment: you should describe the things properly

Comment: question is edited.. sorry for the vague asking.

Answer (score 0):

try this.... u will get answer....

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Select your option: 1 for Write, 2 for Read, 3 for Search, others for exit");
            int flag = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (flag != 1 && flag != 2 && flag != 3) break;

            switch (flag)
            {
                case 1:
                    {
                        StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.txt");
                        while (true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter some value for inset into text file, 0 for exit\n");
                            string temp = Console.ReadLine();

                            if (temp != "0")
                            {
                                SW.WriteLine(temp);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        //SW.Dispose();
                        SW.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    {
                        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt");
                        while (true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(SR.ReadLine());
                            if (SR.EndOfStream == true)
                                break;
                        }
                        SR.Dispose();
                        SR.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    {
                        Console.Write("entre ur value:\t");
                        string value = Console.ReadLine();
                        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(@"C:\test.txt");
                        bool flg = false;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if (value == SR.ReadLine())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(value + " was found in ur text");
                                flg = true;
                                break;
                            }
                            if (SR.EndOfStream == true)
                                break;
                        }
                        if (flg != true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Sorry not found");
                        }
                        SR.Dispose();
                        SR.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }

            }
        }
    }
```